# How do you install pip for python3.9.4?

Tags: 20.04, python3, pip

I haven't found a way to install pip for python3.9 . When I run the command `sudo apt install python3-pip` it installs pip for pythpn3.8, not 3.9. If I try to use `sudo apt install python3.9-pip` it gives an error.

I want to install `numpy`, but if I use `pip3 install numpy` it installs it for python3.8 and not 3.9.

**Ubuntu version is 20.04**

Comment: What version of Ubuntu it matters.

Comment: Yes sorry, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install `pip` for `python3.9` using `get-pip.py` as the [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) as well as the [github page](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip) describes it:

```bsh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py
```

This script will also place binaries in your `~/.local/bin`, so you can optionally add this directory to `PATH`.

```bsh
echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

When you do that, you might want to remove `~/.local/bin/pip` and `~/.local/bin/pip3` and only keep `~/.local/bin/pip3.9` to not replace the already available commands.

---

Finally, check the proper installation:

```
$ pip3.9 -V
pip 21.0.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: Note for me this REQUIRED linux to be rebooted. It just would not pick up the change otherwise.